# Budiling small wine cellar rising from the ground

Tags: home-automation

I am not sure is it a correct place where should I ask that question, but I would like to build a small version of that rising from the ground wine cellar: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QJn94rGJ3Y

First of all, this version is for hundreds of bottles, at the beginning I would like to build a mini version for only 1 bottle. Could someone tell me how to find and where buy proper engine/lift for sth like that?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: But maybe you could help me with how to find or what is the name of that engine/lift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question isn't necessarily a shopping question so much as an identifier type of question. Rephrased it could read "what type of lift is capable of this movement?"

To that end, a hydraulic ram of sufficient travel is the most likely, as such a device is going to be reasonably quiet, powerful and smooth. It's possible, but much less likely that this uses a pneumatic actuator, as the hisses of air would be considered objectionable. One aspect of a hydraulic device is the requirement of a pump, fluid and storage tank.

The image below is of a 24" travel unit from [Automation Direct](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/home/home), for less than US$200

[image: Hydraulic actuator 24" travel]

Another option is a linear actuator. It's a better home-brew solution, in my opinion, as it incorporates the motor and the ram and would also be available in sufficient travel range.

The image below is from [Firgelli Automations](https://www.firgelliauto.com/), also a 24" travel and is mostly self-contained, requiring only electricity and switching, under US$200.00.

[image: linear actuator 24 inch]

Another choice for construction is the rack and pinion design. A straight rack is going to have load limitations, but one could incorporate a worm gear into the mix to overcome that aspect, with a minor increase in complexity.

This image below, from [Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/worm-gear-rack-and-pinion.html), shows a portion of a worm gear rack and pinion device. This is the most complex of the options, as it requires additional fabrication. There may be off-the-shelf items available, but the work involved points to the other two choices as better solutions.

[image: rack and pinion worm gear]

This question is better suited to the Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: Shut up and take my money. I’ve got to have one. Thanks for making it so clear as to how to do it. I’ll finally be able to impress my in-laws.